# Set option on window without going to the window and come back

Tags: vimscript, vim-windows, window-management

I want to set some options on a particular window number. What I've been doing is go to the window by `{winnr} wincmd w`, set some options and do some work then come back. But this creates a UI flash (you can see you changed window for a short amount of time).

Is there any way to modify window options without going there programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `setwinvar` can change options using the `&` syntax:

```
call setwinvar(1, "&list", 0)
```

You can execute any code in the context of another window using `win_execute` (vim only):

```
call win_execute(winid, 'set syntax=python')
```

In neovim there is also `nvim_win_set_option`

```
call nvim_win_set_option(win, 'list', 0)
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't see a `win_execute` help? I'm using nvim 0.5.0.

Comment: Also is it possible to create a window without go to it?

Comment: `win_execute` is vim only, not in neovim.    And I don't know of a way to create a window without changing cursor to the window.

Comment: Alright I see. Missing win_execute is quite inconvenient...

Another similar question: Is there a way to clear the buffer with given buffer number without going to the buffer? I was using `1,$ delete` but that deletes what's in the current buffer. I'm looking for something akin to `setbufline`?

Comment: `deletebufline()`, but consider asking a new question

Comment: Thanks you very much!